# Syntax error: Invalid statement python-pygame

Tags: python

I am learning to make a role playing game in Python by watching some tutorials on Youtube. The guy didn't show me how to setup anything to get it working. I did get pygame and stuff working by watching other videos. Anyway here is my error and code:

```
#!C:\python32
class Character:
def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp

c = Character("Test", 5)
print c.name
print c.hp
```

Error:

> File "C:\Users\Johnathan\Desktop\My Game\character\character.py", line 8
>   print c.name
>            ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 `print` is a function, not a statement.

Try:

```
print(c.name)
```

Also you are missing an indentation after `class Character:`. (Rule of thumb: After most colons follows either a single statement on the same line, or an indented suite of statements.) Your code should read:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, hp):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp

c = Character("Test", 5)
print(c.name)
print(c.hp)
```